# configure laravel without making virtual host

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I am new bee in Laravel. I have able to run it by making virtual host as given in this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/building-web-applications-from-scratch-with-laravel/) .

But I is there any other way to configure and run laravel correctly without touching my conf file or without creating virtual host? I haven't find any answer on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open CLI, Navigate to your laravel root folder

`$ cd ./path/to/laravel-installation`

and type for Laravel 4:

`$ php artisan serve`

For laravel 3 type:

`$ php -S localhost:8000 -t public`

Now you can access it at `localhost:8000` on your browser

Comment: I have tried this. It give me "Could not open input file: artisan"

Comment: Is there anything more to do?

Comment: when you `cd` to your laravel root folder (that's not the /app/ folder) you should see an 'artisan' executable, if not; wrong folder. Try to search for artisan.

Comment: As @RobGordijn said its the laravel root folder. For instance I have a laravel project in localhost I would cd to c:\wamp\www\laravelproject then run the commands above